# LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX using bucket root only loads some files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I have about 2M+ records across ~600 CSV files in a single bucket all at the root level - not in any subfolders. The files all start with a unique ID number of 3-6 digits. If I do the following command:

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://my-bucket/'
        IGNORE INTO TABLE `my_table`
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Only about 500k records are loaded into the table. But if I do a sequence of commands starting with 1-9 then eventually I get the expected row count of data loaded into the table.

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://my-bucket/1'
...
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://my-bucket/2'
...
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://my-bucket/3'
...
...
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://my-bucket/9'
```

According to the docs, it does not appear you can use wildcard `*` in prefix string. I'm at a loss as to why this isn't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Update, figured out the issue. The files were being overwritten/replaced as part of an update process. If a file/object was in the middle of being written to then the LOAD from S3 would stop on that file. The solution was to prefix the updates with a timestamp instead of writing on top of the same file names over and over.